# How to set abyss theme for komodo ide's editor?

Tags: komodo

AFter I change komodo ide's default skin to abyss, the ui interface does change. But the main edit area did not change. How could I change it too?

[image]

Comment: i'm having opposite prob, i CANT get original skin to show anymore!

Answer (score 1):

The skin choice (e.g. Abyss) affects the UI, not the code/edit view.  Try ***Edit > Preferences > Fonts & Colors***